# Input multiple iFrame Source from Form Input with http

Tags: forms, iframe

I have the following code that I found on here.
If I type in http://google.com

It loads google.com into the iframe.

My question is,

1. How can I have more than 1 iframe to be filled
2. Can I have it so that I do not have to put in http:// just the domain, google.com

Thanks, Here is the code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Blah</title>
          <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

             <script type="text/javascript">

               function SetSrc()
               {
                   document.getElementById("myIfreme").src = document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
               }

            </script>
   </head>
<body>

<form>
     Enter URL:
     <input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
     <input type="button" value="GO" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>

     <iframe id="myIfreme" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="500" width="480">   
     </iframe>

     <iframe id="myIfreme" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="500" width="840"> 
     </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks alot. That is exactly what I was looking for! Here it is completed:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Blah</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetSrc()
{
document.getElementById("myIfreme1").src = 'http://' +   
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
document.getElementById("myIfreme2").src = 'http://' + 
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
document.getElementById("myIfreme3").src = 'http://' + 
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
document.getElementById("myIfreme4").src = 'http://' + 
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
document.getElementById("myIfreme5").src = 'http://' + 
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
document.getElementById("myIfreme6").src = 'http://' + 
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter URL:  http://
<input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
<input type="button" value="GO" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>
<div style="clear:both">320 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme1" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="320" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both">480 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme2" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="480" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both">640 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme3" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="640" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both">800 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme4" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="800" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both">1024 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme5" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="1024" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both">1280 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme6" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="1280"     
scrolling="yes"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

THANKS alfasin - You are AWESOME!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Blah</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function SetSrc()
 {
     document.getElementById("myIfreme1").src = document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
     document.getElementById("myIfreme2").src = document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter URL:
<input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
<input type="button" value="GO" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>
<iframe id="myIfreme1" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="500" width="480">
</iframe>
<iframe id="myIfreme2" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="500" width="840">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want the user to enter `http://` you can do:

```
...
<form>
Enter URL:  http://
<input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
...
```

and

```
function SetSrc()
{
    document.getElementById("myIfreme1").src = 'http://' + document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
    document.getElementById("myIfreme2").src = 'http://' + document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
}
```

BTW, Google will block you from using `www.google.com` in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks. That works on the multiple iframes, do you know know I can do away with having to enter http:// in front of the domains. -- funny -- I did not know google did that.

Comment: @user2518599 please checkout the last section of my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! If you tick the answer (top left corner) it means that the answer was accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked it. I'm a noob to stackoverflow. I just added another question, how would I add the onkeypress, enter button to submit the form, in case you want to look at it. The same code above.